# Web Deployment Project failed to map path for include virtual

Tags: asp.net, include, web-deployment-project

I am building my site with a web deployment project but the build fails with a number of errors all relating to the "#include virtual" directives in my master page.

The includes are necessary to import a set of centrally managed html template files.

Here is an example of the include directive and associated error:

```
<!-- #include virtual="/v3/sits/pdpdev/assets-templates/inc/head.html" -->

/PDPRegistration.csproj/Pages/ContentPage.Master(15): 
error ASPPARSE: Failed to map the path 
'/v3/sits/pdpdev/assets-templates/inc/head.html'.
```

The error for each included file actually appears multiple times.  I'm not sure what is being mapped or why, but this was never a problem until I started using WDP (which I wanted to alter web.config depending on the build environment, among other things.)

The project is built locally on my PC and then copied to the web server via a mapped drive.  I found a few solutions on the 'net involving IIS metabase - they weren't quite clear to me, and I'm not sure if they apply given how I build and deploy the project (that is, would I have to build on the same system as IIS in order to make use of the metabase?)

Can anyone suggest how I can get my project to build with WDP?

Comment: Is the checkbox that says "allow this precompiled site to be updatable" checked? http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/cc163448.fig01_L%28en-us%29.gif

Comment: It was.. I just unchecked it and tried another build with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Although SSI's are available within the Framework, the preferred way of doing `include` is to wrap the content from the file into a `User Control` (`.ascx`) as per the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3207d0e3%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)   See also: [support.microsoft.com/kb/306575](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306575)